# Number of Requests Apache can handle (Ajax)

Tags: php, ajax, apache, multiplayer

What to do:
To create a multiplayer ("realtime" like) browsergame with lets say +- 12 players, I want to use Ajax for asyncronous requests to Apache.

Question:
How should the requesting for the game updates be implemented?
Is it recommended to e.g. that each client requests (POST) the full game status from the server every 250ms / 500ms / Xms?
Can Apache handle this? There will be individual client requests additionally (mouse clicks etc.).

Example, request amount per second:

12 x 4 + 12 x 4 = 96 req/sec to apache and back

[Each player automatically updates 4 times a second
and approx. clicks 4 times a second]

Add:
I know it is not scalable. There is a fix limit of players. Technologies: PHP, Mysql, jquery

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that asyncronous HTTP is not the best solution for this. Try COMET instead.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at Ajax Push Engine: http://www.ape-project.org/

Answer (score 0):

To find out what is the responce capability of Apache you can run a stress test. This will show you what is the exact ammount of responces Apache can hanlde